# Are mathematical physics and theoretical physics the same thing at highest levels?

Tags: mathematical-physics, terminology, soft-question

To my understanding Mathematical physics is about how one could find a rigorous basis to understand physics/ study the mathematics used in physics. However, high level theoretical modern physics like String theory, M-theory etc, it seems so they are theories derived totally from mathematics with theory building the aim in itself.

So, does this mean that at the highest level theoretical physics and mathematical physics are the same thing , and, the distinction is only important in lower levels?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56293/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627664/2451 and links therein.